# Dropdown click background

Tags: bootstrap-4, dropdown

[I want to remove click color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXQXm.png)

I want to remove click color (is not a hover) in a bootstrap dropdown but i dont know how to change that color, i tried with DevTools but i didnt find the solution, thank you

```html
<li>
    <a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-placement="bottom">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Acción #1</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Acción #4</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: it's css class :active. So "a:active: {background-color: red; }

Answer (score 0):

Add pseudo style to your button.

There are more pseudo events than `hover` you can check them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

```html
<a type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="customButton" data-placement="bottom">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></span>
</a>
```

with the styles

```css
.customButton:link, .customButton:focus, .customButton:active, .customButton:visited{
  //whatever you want
}
```

I've added a `customButton` class to the button, add whatever proprietry you need in the CSS

Comment: if you can put a working code in a sandbox, or codepen, I can help you further. Also I forgot to add `.` to the class name in the CSS, I've updated the response

Comment: sorry i can´t is from my work, i can´t share codes, thank you so much